# Jsoup is not working with a webpage

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get URL's of some images from a webpage but I'm having problems. I'm using try.jsoup.org to parse HTML via a CSS Query `img` and get result:

```
<img src="https://d5nxst8fruw4z.cloudfront.net/atrk.gif?account=JwbPi1a4ZP00iy" style="display:none" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
<img src="http://ads.tamtay.vn/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=226&cb=INSET_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&n=aa2b62d0" border="0" alt="" />
<img src="http://a0.ttimg.vn/866392.ava" style="width: 100%;" />
```

I know getting these urls is very easy by `attr("abs:src")`, but in this case, it doesn't work, and returns `null`.

I try to change current webpage by other webpage. It work normal. I think problem come from webpage. not code. Any one can help?

Comment: Show us the code. What does the document look like, that you are getting? Some sites might return different content to spiders, robots and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put "abs" try only with "src"

[Documentation de JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Answer (score 0):

here is code:

```
 private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://photo.tamtay.vn").get();
                Element image = document.select("img").first();
                Log.d("Image", image.attr("abs:src"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        }
    }
```

image.attr("abs:src") return null